# Learning Combinatorics Further

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, self-learning

I have completed most of the basic parts in Combinatorics like Generalised Permutation & Combination, Recurrence relations, Pigeonhole Principle,  Formal power series, Stirling no, Catalan no, Inclusion exclusion principle, Derangements etc, I want to know what all topics I can learn further as a part of self study in like a period of 2 months and what books, notes, video lectures etc I can follow for it, and if possible can give some brief detail of the topics that I have to study and do I need to know a lot of Calculus to study these topics as I have a very limited knowledge of Calculus.

Comment: Do you want all kind of combinatorics, or only counting problems?

Comment: @wythagoras I don't know what you mean by all kind or only counting problems..., from what I have encountered till now all problems were related to counting something usually

Comment: For example this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277420/move-elements-in-a-grid-combinatorics

Comment: @wythagoras Then i am interested in all kinds of combinatorics and i do know the pigeonhole principle, i will edit the question to include it.

Comment: There’s a lot of good stuff in Richard Stanley’s Enumerative Combinatorics: http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look to the following things: Burnside's lemma, colouring arguments, invariants, greedy algorithm. That are the most important things that come to mind.